# How to turn off escaping in Postman?

Tags: json, postman

I'm using Postman to test a JSON API. The response includes \r, \n, \t, etc. I'm pretty sure that I'm actually sending x0D, x0A, x09, etc. But is there any way to tell is this is an escape for a control character or if I'm actually sending a backslash and an "r"?

Comment: Update: I was wrong, I'm not sending x0D etc. When I serialize the object, the serializer is converting the x0D to \r etc. But that still leaves the question of how I can know in Postman. The way I figured it out was by looking at the content length header and then counting characters, but that's pretty awkward.

Comment: Hi - when I send a binary file from Postman, I notice that it automatifcally adds \r in the uploaded file. Do you know about this?